# Force MongoDB Replica Set to use IP instead of hostname during creation

Tags: mongodb, docker, ip-address, hostname, replicaset

I am setting up MongoDB replica set via Mongo Cloud Manager. Two Mongo instances are being run inside the docker container having a random hostname. During the creation MongoDB sets container's hostname as member's host in the configuration (rs.conf().members[i].host field). Due to this I cannot access this replica set as container's hostname is not visible from outside of container.

I don't want to do any additional manual setup on container's host to make container's hostname visible (as there is already network set up by Docker and container has specific IP by which it is accessible from outside).

Is there a way to force MongoDB to use IP instead of hostname during replica set creation?

I have tried with bind_ip option but got the error: "Invalid config: bind_ip 172.17.0.2 does not contain a valid localhost address"

Thanks for stopping by! Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Cloud Manager gets the hostname from the OS `hostname` command.  Is making that return an IP an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Joe, thanks for your advice! The idea is interesting, the only concern I have is whether it can affect something else in the container's OS itself. I will consider this as a solution

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have decided to pass --hostname with IP address of container's host (Inspired by @Joe's comment) when running docker image with Mongo Cloud Automation Agent. I understand that it is pretty ugly solution but I believe it is ok as there is no other then mongo related stuff (controlled by the Automation) inside the container.

And for DB dedicated to be used only locally (on container's host) I am just passing static IP of the container (I use docker-compose with configured network and it's static IP set to the container)

Other solutions like manual creation of replica set and importing to Mongo CLoud Manager (most relevant one, I think) or Trying to fix hosts manually after the deployment creation via mongo console don't worth their complexity, as for me.